# GetProcessTimes ExitTime from an unelevated process

Tags: c, windows, winapi, process

Is it possible to get the Exit Time of other users processes from an unelevated process?
It is possible to get the Exit Time of other users processes from an elevated process with GetProcessTimes on a previously opened handle of the dead process

NB: It's possible to get the start time of another users process unelevated using NtQuerySystemInformation to enumerate the running processes.

WMI [win32_process](https://powershell.one/wmi/root/cimv2/win32_process#terminationdate) queries require same admin privilege according to MS documentation although there is conflicting documentation. I've worked with WMI queries in this way through the COM interface. It may be that this will not work as a previously opened dead process handle is not how it works, it's a query.

The following is not what I'm looking for.

The [WMI events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/krnlprov/win32-processstarttrace) are documented as giving the time stamp of the event. Called from the COM interface requires careful multithreading. Not the exit time of the process. I have tested getting these events

I've worked with the [pssetcreateprocessnotifyroutine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddk/nf-ntddk-pssetcreateprocessnotifyroutine)  but timing is not included and found it to be less reliable than polling

Comment: if you can open process with `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` than can. with debug privileges you can open any process with `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` access, but without it not any. however for what this need ?

Comment: No elevation required, [sample C# code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,292)

Comment: @HansPassant elevation is required to get exit time of other users processes

Comment: @RbMm As I understand it a process has to be admin to have debug privileges?

Comment: @JanS in general yes. by default admin account have debug privileges

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you cannot succeed to `OpenProcess` with `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` or `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` which is the access right that request, Unless you have the Debug Privilege. Then there is no vaild process handle that can be passed to `GetProcessTimes`.

By default, members of the Administrators group have this right.

If you want to assign the privilege: [User Rights Assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/user-rights-assignment)

Further: [If you grant somebody SeDebugPrivilege, you gave away the farm](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080314-00/?p=23113)

Comment: see edit to original question regarding NtQuerySystemInformation

Comment: What do you want to achieve, if you want to monitor the process creation and delete events of another user, I suggest you use win32 WMI, see [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/example--receiving-event-notifications-through-wmi-) and add the delete event with `__InstanceDeletionEvent` as  `__InstanceCreationEvent`. And if the process has a handle to be held open when deleting, you could also get the [`TerminationDate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-process)

Comment: It would be the TerminationDate from Win32_Process https://powershell.one/wmi/root/cimv2/win32_process#terminationdate. I've read admin access rights are required for WMI?

Comment: I can use `Win32_Process` to get the `ProcessId` and `CreationDate` when get create/delete event, and according to the document, If privileges are required by a property, it will be listed. Like `ExecutablePath` in [`Win32_Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-process)

Comment: I get a NULL value return by `TerminationDate` when receive the delete event, because all the handle to the process has been close.